# Flutter. Global tcp client for all widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, tcpclient

I try to write an app, which connects to tcp server. App has two pages. In first page I declare tcp cocket, connect to server and display some data. Then i want to display second page, and make some other requests to server. How can i refer to tcp socket in second page?
Also i want the second page to be able to change its contents when i show it according to data received from server. So, how can i chande widgets in second page, when i push button on first page?

I have no idea how it can be reached.

Comment: make tcp object in main() method and declare it globally. it will be accessible everywhere